# Concurrent Development of PHP Standalone & Wordpress-plugin version. Possible?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to develop a specific PHP script and wanted to release it as both standalone and as Wordpress plugin. I wanted to generate the standalone and WP-plugin version from the same codebase if possible. Please pardon me if I come across as naive :-)

I wanted to know if anybody has ever tried or knows any guide on how to do this?
Please toss in your 2 cents.

I have searched high and low on the internet but there seems to be very limited information on this topic.

Thanks in advance for your insight!

Comment: Sure it's *possible* fundamentally. How much effort it would be, I guess will depend on the nature of your script and what functions it would use.

Comment: Do you know of a PHP project that develops standalone and Wordpress-plugin versions concurrently?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, no.